# What options other than BitNami are there for easy Rails stack deployments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bitnami

I've been having some odd issues with BitNami, especially when trying to deploy it on a system that already has a Rails stack elsewhere. I'd like to know what the alternatives are (if any) for easy deployment like the stacks BitNami offers. If nothing else, it'll just be neat to shop around. :)

Answer (score 1):

What issues are you running into?  We designed [BitNami RubyStack](http://bitnami.org/stacks/rubystack) so it would work despite existing Rails stacks (checks for ports, etc.) so we would be very interested in tracking down your issues and fixing them.

As for alternatives, if you are using Windows you can take a look at [InstantRails](http://instantrails.rubyforge.org/wiki/wiki.pl)

Comment: Daniel, I am having trouble deploying my Rails app to Bitnami/Google App Engine. I have successfully linked Bitnami and Google App Engine but nowhere are there directions on how to deploy an active Rails app to the Ruby stack. How can this be accomplished? view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910547/deploying-ruby-on-rails-on-google-app-engine-with-bitnami