# Deploying Ruby on Rails on Google Compute Engine with Bitnami

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-compute-engine, bitnami

I have successively linked my Google Compute Engine console and Bitnami, as well as deployed a Ruby Stack. However, I wish to now move my Rails app onto the Ruby stack, but there is no documentation whatsoever on how to do so.

I am running Rails on Windows right now and therefore cannot use Passenger. Below is the file path of Bitnami Ruby stack, but there is no indication where to place the Rails files:

[image]

How can I deploy my Rails app onto Google Compute Engine/Bitnami?

Comment: ever figure out a good way to do this? the ruby "click to deploy" thing for Google seems to not work as advertised.

Comment: No,  I moved to heroku, until we scale it is not worth the inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami developer here,

You can upload files to your Google Cloud Platform instance using a SFTP/SCP client. You can find more information about that our wiki entry at https://wiki.bitnami.com/Google_Cloud_Platform/Servers#How_to_upload_files_to_the_server_with_SFTP.3f

Also, to deploy your custom Ruby on Rails application in your Bitnami Ruby Stack I recommend you to follow our guide at https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/Bitnami_Custom_Ruby_on_Rails_application that will show you how to add your own Ruby on Rails application on top of the Bitnami Ruby Stack the same way as other Ruby on Rails applications are installed in Bitnami.

Best regards,

Gonzalo

Answer (score 0):

The Developers Console provides Ruby Stack under Click-to-Deploy menu.

Comment: That is what I am using, see the first paragraph of my question